# How to split values in column and make a new dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in python

```
ColA   ColB
A      hg_gh | fg_tr | yu_jhd
A      hg_dh | fg_fr 
B      hg_th | fg_er | yu_jkd
C      hg_zh | fg_qr
```

Is there a way to split it and make a new column like below
Basically split all values across different categories in ColA

```
ColA  ColB    
A     hg_gh
A     fg_tr
A     yu_jhd
A     hg_dh
A     fg_fr
B     hg_th
B     fg_er
B     yu_jkd
C     hg_zh
C     fg_qr
```

There is an option to explode it, but unfortunately, lower versions of pandas does not support explode.

Comment: out = df.assign(ColB=df['ColB'].str.split('|')).explode('ColB')

Comment: thanks @PandaKim. But explode is not there in lower version of pandas. :(

Comment: explode() was introduced in Pandas v0.25. Time to update to the latest v2.2?